# Downloading and parsing JSON on Android

Tags: android, json

I just want to ask what is the proper way of converting this into android code using HTTP get..

Basically I need to login to the website and do some specific search...

This is the actual code I have a problem with:

```
curl -H "Content-type: application/json" --basic --user "username:passowrd" -X GET -G \
--data-urlencode "status=triggered" \
--data-urlencode "assigned_to_user="\
"https://yourdomain.pagerduty.com/api/v1/incidents"
```

I am not sure if I can do that using put..

Example:

```
object.put("--data-urlencode", status=triggered)
```

and also for the username and password I am not sure if I can also do something like this

```
object.put("username", "romel");
object.put("password", "passwd");
```

Comment: Sorry, I cannot be parsed :(

Comment: oppss sorry it was a typo.. :)  I edited my question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your question isn't too detailed so I'm entirely sure what you're looking for - is it an authentication problem or JSON in general?

Handling JSON in Android is pretty well covered in a few places, including [Vogella's tutorial](http://www.vogella.com/articles/AndroidJSON/article.html).

Writing JSON is pretty easy, as in Vogella's example:

```
public void writeJSON() { 

 JSONObject object = new JSONObject();
 try {
    object.put("name", "Jack Hack");
    object.put("score", new Integer(200));
    object.put("current", new Double(152.32));
    object.put("nickname", "Hacker");
  } catch (JSONException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
  }
  System.out.println(object);
}
```

Headers for things like content type are easy to add on your HTTPGet object as well, for example:

```
HttpGet httpGet = new HttpGet(API_URL);
        httpGet.setHeader("Accept", "application/json");
        httpGet.setHeader("Content-type", "application/json");
```

These are only snippets, use the tutorial linked above for a better, fuller explanation. Hope this helps.

Comment: yes... I have problem with the authentication. ;)  actually I have this code without code for login..

https://gist.github.com/e3fcd9562cd917714cc4

I am getting "HTTP Basic: Access denied." in return instead of data

Answer (score 1):

If you are having HTTP Basic Auth problems, try this code to set your username and password...

```
HttpURLConnection con;
String basicAuthUsername = "username";
String basicAuthPassword = "passowrd"; //do you have a typo here??
try {
    URL url = new URL(urlString);  
    con = (HttpURLConnection)url.openConnection();

    if (basicAuthUsername != null && basicAuthPassword != null) {
        String userAndPass = new StringBuilder(basicAuthUsername).append(":").append(basicAuthPassword).toString();
        con.setRequestProperty("Authorization", "Basic " + Base64.encodeToString(userAndPass.getBytes(), Base64.NO_WRAP));
    }

    //con.setRequestMethod("POST");
    con.setRequestMethod("GET");

    con.setUseCaches(false);

    int responseCode = con.getResponseCode();

    //etc...
}
finally {
        //close con, etc.
}
```

...also, maybe you have mistyped your password??